# Angular: Passing an Observable to another service

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a Service "**DataStorageService**" that is responsible for getting data from firebase via HTTP. It looks like this:

```
export class DataStorageService {

  private _data_source_url = "https://a******9.firebaseio.com/";

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  getUsers() {
    return this._http.get(this._data_source_url + "users.json")
      .map((response: Response) => {
        return response.json();
      });
  }

}
```

I'm using another Service "**UsersService**" to get this data into an array of Users. It looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService{

  private _users: User[];
  public usersChanged = new Subject<User[]>();

  constructor(private _dataStorageService: DataStorageService) {}

  public getUsers(): User[] {
    this._dataStorageService.getUsers()
      .subscribe((users: User[]) => {
        this._users = users;
        this.usersChanged.next(users);
      });
    return this._users.slice();
  }

}
```

I'm trying to access the array from a component using this **getUsers()** method from the **UsersService**. But, I get no data which *I think is because the getUsers doesn't wait for the data to return from the subscribe and executes return statement which has nothing at the time*. But I can't think of any solution that could solve this issue.

I need some expert advice on this. Also, Is my approach correct to do such a task?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this in your component?

```
this.usersService.usersChanged.subscribe(users => {
this.componentUserVariable = users
})
```

Comment: I have to call getUsers somewhere in order to emit the event first. Also, I'm trying to get data from a function, am I wrong?

Comment: You are already calling getUsers from your service, you just need to subscribe usersChanged in your component

Comment: but who would call the getUsers of the UsersService?

Comment: Bro you can call it inside the constructor of your service itself, or you can call it before subscribing to it in your component